# How to preserve the hyperlinks in a PDF file

Tags: conversion

I'm formatting my mathematical book into an ebook. To keep all mathematical symbols intact, I saved it as a `.PDF`. Is there any software that can preserve both mathematical symbols and the hyperlink for chapters in the final `.MOBI` file?

As a side note, the kindle comic creator can preserve all symbols, but not the functionality of hyperlinks.

Comment: Have you tried Calibre yet?